# Facebook Post deep link (app links ) to iOS app

Tags: html, facebook

I am posting on Facebook wall through HTML page i have added all meta tags on page as well as configured bundle id & appstore id on facebook console also. When i am clicking on post it's redirecting to facebook internal browser but i want to open my app if it's installed or redirect to app store if not.

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="artist://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="49155" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Artist" />

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="805534" />

<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://fbdigi.hua.org/AAD/AA_app_icon.png" />

</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code & it worked:

Final App link code:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="artist://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="49155" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Artist" />
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="805534" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://fbdigi.hua.org/AAD/AA_app_icon.png" />

</head>
</html>
```